# Apache-commons-fileupload: how to read and display the data in a temporary file uploaded into server directory by spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-commons-fileupload, apache-commons-io

I am working on a service project, who's UI allows its users to upload a file. I need to write a service that can upload this file to server and read and display the contents of this file. Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

```
//Controller definition begins
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();


        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                logger.info("Server File Location="
                        + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;    

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name
                    + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

Now i want to know how i can display the contents of the uploaded file. It is being converted to FILE format and is stored in the tempfiles directory of the tomcat server and the data is non-human readable.I need to convert this back to xlsx(file being uploaded is xlsx) or be able to read the data from it directly to update the Db.Also i am using apache commons-io and file upload in Spring MVC as you can see from above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a library capable of reading xlsx file types, such as [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)

In case you choose this library, there is a [very good example section in the example secion of it's website](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)

Comment: is there a way to directly get the content from the file ?